# Save a variable in succession with "for" loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I need to save the sum of results from a loop with `for`.

The results shown are only a list of the values of variable `n`, but not the sum of these values.

```
for(i in 1:10){
 n=1/(i+1)^2
 m=sum(n)
 print(m)
 }
[1] 0.25
[1] 0.1111111
[1] 0.0625
[1] 0.04
[1] 0.02777778
[1] 0.02040816
[1] 0.015625
[1] 0.01234568
[1] 0.01
[1] 0.008264463
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the operations in R are vectorized, so you can use them instead of `for` loop.

In this case, we can do

```
i <- 1:10
ans <- sum((1/(i+1))^2)
ans
#[1] 0.558
```

and if you have to use a `for` loop you can need to store all the values in a vector using index. Currently, you are just overwriting the previous value with the new value calculated.

```
n <- numeric(length = 10L)
for(i in seq_along(n)) {
  n[i] = 1/(i+1)^2
}
ans <- sum(n)
```